# Can't add secondary gateway for secondary interface in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, network-interface, iproute, gateway, netplan

I have two interfaces and both of them have a public IP address. One of them (eth0) is primary and the other one (eth1) is secondary. I'm trying to setup it through netplan + iproute2. When I was on Ubuntu 18.04 everything worked fine.

/etc/iproute2/rt_tables:

```
#
# reserved values
#
255     local
254     main
253     default
0       unspec
#
# local
#
#1      inr.ruhep
801 801
800 800
```

My netplan config was this:

```yaml
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    eth1: 
      addresses: 
      - 10.0.2.10/24
      gateway4: 10.0.2.1
      mtu: 1500 
      nameservers: 
        addresses: 
        - 8.8.8.8 
        - 8.8.4.4 
        search: [] 
      routes: 
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0 
          via: 10.0.2.1 
          metric: 50
          table: 800
      routing-policy: 
        - from: 10.0.2.10 
          table: 800 
          priority: 100
    eth0:
      addresses:
      - 10.0.1.10/24
      mtu: 1500
      gateway4: 10.0.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 8.8.4.4
        search: []
      routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 10.0.1.1
          metric: 100
          table: 801
      routing-policy:
        - from: 10.0.1.10
          table: 801
          priority: 200
```

Since Ubuntu 22.04 (or even earlier) the `gateway4` property is deprecated and isn't using anymore. After upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04 I removed `gateway4` property. But now it's not working

```yaml
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    eth1:
      addresses:
      - 10.0.2.10/24
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 8.8.4.4
      routes:
      - metric: 50
        to: 0.0.0.0/0
        via: 10.0.2.1
        table: 800
      routing-policy:
      - from: 10.0.2.10
        table: 800
        priority: 100
    eth0:
      addresses:
      - 10.0.1.10/24
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 8.8.4.4
      routes:
      - metric: 100
        to: 0.0.0.0/0
        via: 10.0.1.1
        table: 801
      routing-policy:
      - from: 10.0.1.10
        table: 801
        priority: 200
```

Moreover, after `netplan apply` I'm trying `route -n` and I don't see any gateway! Is netplan or iproute2 broken or do I need to change some configs?

Comment: Still didn't find a solution. Just uninstalled 22.04 and installed 18.04 and everything works fine